# cassandra field string vs. long

Tags: java, schema, cassandra, astyanax

Ok, I am turning crazy here.  There are number of behaviors that I cannot explain with Cassandra and I am not even sure whether they are related or not.

I created a table as follows (not showing all columns for the sake of brevity):

```
create column family cachekey  
    with comparator = UTF8Type  
    and column_metadata =  
    [  
    {  
        column_name : accountNumber,  
        validation_class : UTF8Type  
    },  
    {  
        column_name : homeId,  
        validation_class : LongType  
    }  
 ...  
];
```

Some records were added to that table (not by me).  Now, when I display the schema, I am not sure why I do not see the columns that I created

```
[default@cachekeydata] show schema;
...

use cachekeydata;

create column family cachekey  
  with column_type = 'Standard'  
  and comparator = 'UTF8Type'  
  and default_validation_class = 'BytesType'  
  and key_validation_class = 'BytesType'  
  and read_repair_chance = 0.1  
  and dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0  
  and gc_grace = 864000  
  and min_compaction_threshold = 4  
  and max_compaction_threshold = 32  
  and replicate_on_write = true  
  and compaction_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'  
  and caching = 'KEYS_ONLY'  
  and compression_options = {'sstable_compression' :   'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.SnappyCompressor'};
```

Now, what is really puzzling me: when I pull data from my java code, I get a null pointer exception when attempting to retrieve a long but not when retrieving a string for some of the records:

```
System.out.println("Mac=" + mac);
System.out.println("  cidx=<" + result.getStringValue("homeId",null) + ">");
System.out.println("  cidx=<" + result.getLongValue("homeId",null) + ">");
System.out.println("  cidx=<" + result.getColumnByName("homeId").getLongValue() + ">");
```

leads to:

```
Mac=001DD67CFF46
  cidx=<50190074>
  cidx=<3832617404583655220>
  cidx=<3832617404583655220>
Mac=001DCFE2122C
  cidx=<3663580>
```

followed by a NullPointerException.  In other words, result.getStringValue("homeId",null) returns 3663580 but result.getLongValue("homeId",null) causes a NullPointerException when running the following line inside the Cassandra library code:

```
LongSerializer.get().fromBytes(column.getValue());
```

Last, displaying these same two records as above from the cli console do not show anything suspicious to me:

```
[default@cachekeydata] get cachekey[utf8('001DD67CFF46')];
=> (column=accountNumber, value=30373833373132303730323036, timestamp=1361305382124)
=> (column=corp, value=3037383337, timestamp=1361305382124)
=> (column=homeId, value=3530313930303734, timestamp=1361305382124)
=> (column=zip, value=3130343732, timestamp=1361305382124)
Returned 4 results.
Elapsed time: 70 msec(s).
[default@cachekeydata] get cachekey[utf8('001DCFE2122C')];
=> (column=accountNumber, value=30373830383132333437323032, timestamp=1361305376659)
=> (column=corp, value=3037383038, timestamp=1361305376659)
=> (column=homeId, value=33363633353830, timestamp=1361305376659)
=> (column=zip, value=3036393033, timestamp=1361305376659)
Returned 4 results.
Elapsed time: 45 msec(s).
```

My questions:

- Q1. the big question. Why do I get a null pointer in the example above?
- Q2. The smaller ones:

  - Q2a. is what I observe in 3 normal given how I set up the table in 1?
  - Q2b. why do my string and long values do not match?

Comment: Are you sure the value written to `homeId` is a long?

Comment: I am sure that I set the validation_class as LongType when I created the table.  I do not know how one might have populated the table, and that is essentially my question: given how I created the table, how would one enter data in that table to cause the behavior I described above?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the answer will be useful to anyone, but the data that were expected to be long were inserted as string.  This apparently caused at least two issues that I explained above:

- displaying a different result whether the data was read as String or Long (something I wasn't used to coming from the Oracle world)
- causing these occasional null pointer exceptions

Comment: CQL gives you better type safety than the bytebuffer-based Thrift api.  The first pure CQL java driver is at https://github.com/datastax/java-driver